# Creating a class in anonymous apex causes compile error

Tags: community, developer-console, execute-anonymous, gack

Attempting to run the following code as anonymous apex generates an error:

```
public class YoYo{
    String abc;
    Integer i;  
    Double d;
        public YoYo(){

        }
    public YoYo(String abc,Integer i, Double d){
            this.abc=abc;
            this.i=i;
            this.d=d;
        }
}

YoYo t = new YoYo();
```

Error:
 UNKNOWN ERROR: apex.bytecodeinterpreter.InterpreterRuntimeException: Unable to load class: esw/anon$YoYo Error Id: 1024384784-261701 (1978825992)

What causes the error?

Comment: When I copy + paste this and run it it compiles and executes.

Comment: @Ajay  Did you write the code yourself, or cut/paste from another source?

Comment: Do you actually have that class in your org? Go to `Setup -> Develop -> Apex Classes` to verify it is in the org that you are attempting to execute the script on.

Comment: No, I want to try it on developer console.

Comment: Works for me too, where are you running it from, dev console, ide, etc?

Comment: @cyberjus I want to run the code in dev console.

Comment: Works fine for me in the dev console. Make sure you dont have any extra characters in there. Otherwise you have to give that number to salesforce support, that is an internal salesforce error.

Comment: The error occurs when the code is run in a packaging org with a namespace defined.  Note that the error is trying to load the class from the esw namespace.